# What's the difference between GlobalMaxPool1D and GlobalMaxPooling1D?

Tags: keras

In this tutorial [here](https://blog.mimacom.com/text-classification/), the author used `GlobalMaxPool1D()` like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, Flatten, GlobalMaxPool1D, Dropout, Conv1D
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam

filter_length = 300

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 20, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv1D(filter_length, 3, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.summary()

callbacks = [
    ReduceLROnPlateau(),
    EarlyStopping(patience=4),
    ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model-conv1d.h5', save_best_only=True)
]

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    class_weight=class_weight,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=32,
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

However, after searching online, I could only find `GlobalMaxPooling1D` on Keras site [here](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/). Are they the same? If not, what's the difference in terms of function and usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the same thing. See here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalMaxPool1D

Answer (score 1):

I would add that the same is available for other layers, such as Conv2D == Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D == MaxPool2D.